# OAuth2.0 Authorization-Code Flow w/ OpenID is set up, When and How do I access my SQL Server to retrieve data specific for that user?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, web-development-server

I'm confused about this. I think it involves authorization but I may be wrong.

I'm using the authorization code-flow for OAuth2.0 with OpenID Connect to Authenticate my user to my app.
Here's what it looks like so far:

Click Sign in with Google --> User gives permissions to authorization server --> I retrieve an authorization code --> Send code to node.js/express backend --> Code and Secret are sent to authorization server --> Backend gets access code and ID Token --> ID token sent to front end to read --> Access code posted to Resource Server --> Retrieve additional google information --> Sent to front end.

Now that I have an access token, and ID Token, how do I retrieve data from my SQL database that is specific for that user? Let's say the database is hosted by another server. Do I have to do something with my access token or ID token to authorize the request first? Where would I add accessing the SQL server in this process? What if I want to get the data and display it on the final callback URI after logging in?

Any extra info would be very helpful. If i'm wrong about anything, please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access token is used to gain access to resources and resources are typical APIs. The ID-token is only used to create a "login"-session.

I doubt if any database supports access token directly, instead you would create an API (like a REST or GraphQL API) in front of your database that will take the tokens and authorize the caller to access the information in the database. The REST API is also in charge of validating the tokens, typically using the public signing key from the  authorization server.